# Redirect to Java Servlet in Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay

i'm not sure, if i doing this right. I'm new to web development and what i am trying to create is a portlet and a specific jsp with an html form, which calls a java servlet.

The code is basically like this

```
<form id="contact_form" action="sendmail" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

and

```
public class SendMail extends HttpServlet{

     public doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
             throws IOException{
       ....
                }
}
```

i also changed the properties in the WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
 <web-app>
 ....
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>sendmail</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>test.portlet.profile.SendMail</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>sendmail</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/sendmail</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If i click on the send button of the form, it redirects me to /sendmail, but i have standard "page not found" errors instead of content defined im my servlet.

Comment: But, why do you want to redirect to a servlet in portlet environment? Aren't you able to achieve it using portlet action?

Comment: Crossposted here https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/70860824 - please also check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form action you wrote **sendmail** and you wrote **SendMail** in servlet file. Both names are different.
Please correct as below:

```
<form id="contact_form"
      action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SERVLETNAME"
      method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

servlet file:

```
public class sendmail extends HttpServlet{

     public doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
             throws IOException{
       ....
                }
}
```

web.xml file as it is.

Comment: I changed the class name, but it doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: <FORM ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SERVLETNAME"> use above code in from action attribute.